# Pandoc fails to embed metadata from the supplied YAML file

Tags: html, yaml, metadata, pandoc

I need to convert some `.xhtml` files to regular `.html` (html5) with *pandoc*, and during the conversion I would like to embed some metadata (supplied via a YAML file) in the final files.

The conversion runs smoothly, but any attempt to embed the metadata invariably fails.

I tried many variations of this command, but it should be something like:

```
pandoc -s -H assets/header -c css/style.css -B assets/prefix -A assets/suffix --metadata-file=metadata.yaml input_file -o output_file --to=html5
```

The error I get is:

> pandoc: unrecognized option `--metadata-file=metadata.yaml'
>   Try pandoc --help for more information.

I really don't get what's wrong with this, since I found this option in the [pandoc manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--metadata-file)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pandoc version is too old. Update to pandoc 2.3 or later.

Comment: This is very true. The latest _Pandoc_ version available in the [Debian (oldstable) repository](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pandoc) is 1.17. Thanks!